# Using flask-sqlalchemy: when I add or change models, I have to restart the app AND nginx

Tags: python, postgresql, nginx, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a weird issue. I'm using Flask, flask-sqlalchemy, a Postgresql db running on an nginx server. Normally when I make updates to my website (routing, templates, whatever) all I have to do is git pull the new files and restart the app.

However, seems like if I ever change or add models, I have to restart the app AND nginx. I don't understand why, and I wish I did. Any ideas?

My whole stack consists of:
Ubuntu linux
Nginx
Postgres
Flask (with flask-sqlalchemy)

Also, I followed this guide when I originally set up my server: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04